# File Upload Error on console and don't know what's the issue. (Uploadthing)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, file-upload

The repo is this: [repo](https://github.com/glaucc/messaging-app)
I'm using uploadthing: https://uploadthing.com/
I got the error code from console.
The error can be related to lib directory or /app/api/uploadthing I assume

I don't know what's wrong and I don't have high-level knowledge. I just followed the tutorial and I can't seem to solve it. The timestamp in video is The timestamp is 2:03:30. Tutorial: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbX4Ok9YX94&t=6384s)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.